# laravel compact() and ->with()

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have a piece of code and I'm trying to find out why one variation works and the other doesn't.

```
return View::make('gameworlds.mygame', compact('fixtures'), compact('teams'))->with('selections', $selections);
```

This allows me to generate a view of arrays for fixtures, teams and selections as expected.

However,

```
return View::make('gameworlds.mygame', compact('fixtures'), compact('teams'), compact('selections'));
```

**does not** allow the view to be generated properly. I can still echo out the arrays and I get the expected results but the view does not render once it arrives at the selections section.

It's oké, because I have it working with the `->with()` syntax but just an odd one.

Thanks.
DS

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The `View::make` function takes **3** arguments which according to the documentation are:

```
public View make(string $view, array $data = array(), array $mergeData = array())
```

In your case, the `compact('selections')` is a *4th* argument. It doesn't pass to the view and laravel throws an exception.

On the other hand, you can use `with()` **as many time as you like**. Thus, this will work:

```
return View::make('gameworlds.mygame')

->with(compact('fixtures'))

->with(compact('teams'))

->with(compact('selections'));
```

Comment: Or `->with(compact('fixtures', 'teams', 'selections'))`

Comment: Or 
`return view('gameworlds.mygame',compact('fixtures','teams','selections'));`

Comment: Or `return view('gameworlds.mygame', ["fixtures"=>$fixtures,...]);`

Answer (score 24):

I just wanted to hop in here and correct (suggest alternative) to the previous answer....

You can actually use compact in the same way, however a lot neater for example...

```
return View::make('gameworlds.mygame', compact(array('fixtures', 'teams', 'selections')));
```

Or if you are using PHP > 5.4

```
return View::make('gameworlds.mygame', compact(['fixtures', 'teams', 'selections']));
```

This is far neater, and still allows for readability when reviewing what the application does ;)

Answer (score 13):

I was able to use

```
return View::make('myviewfolder.myview', compact('view1','view2','view3'));
```

I don't know if it's because I am using PHP 5.5 it works great :)

Answer (score 8):

Laravel Framework 5.6.26

return more than one array then we use `compact('array1', 'array2', 'array3', ...)` to return view.

*`viewblade`* is the frontend (view) blade.

```
return view('viewblade', compact('view1','view2','view3','view4'));
```

Comment: Please add an explaination to your code. Code only solutions are quite useless.

Answer (score 2):

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('greeting', ['name' => 'James']);
});
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello, {{ $name }}</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

or

```
public function index($id)
{
    $category = Category::find($id);
    $topics = $category->getTopicPaginator();
    $message = Message::find(1);

    // here I would just use "->with([$category, $topics, $message])"
    return View::make('category.index')->with(compact('category', 'topics', 'message'));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass array of variables to the compact as an arguement
eg:

```
return view('yourView', compact(['var1','var2',....'varN']));
```

in view:
if var1 is an object
you can use it something like this

```
@foreach($var1 as $singleVar1)
    {{$singleVar1->property}}
@endforeach
```

incase of scalar variable you can simply

```
{{$var2}}
```

i have done this several times without any issues

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = [
   'var1' => 'something',
   'var2' => 'something',
   'var3' => 'something',
];

return View::make('view', $data);
```