# What's the difference between with() and compact() in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

What's the difference between the functions `with()` and `compact()` in Laravel in these two examples:

**Example 1:**

```
return View::make('books.index')->with('booksList', $booksList);
```

**Example 2:**

```
return View::make('books.index',compact('booksList'));
```

Comment: For detail http://stackoverflow.com/a/22413121/6521116

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well `compact()` is a [PHP function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) that converts a list of variables into an associative array where the key is the variable name and the value the actual value of that variable.

The actual question should be: What is the difference between

```
return View::make('books.index')->with('booksList', $booksList);
```

and

```
return View::make('books.index', array('booksList' => $booksList));
```

The answer there isn't really one. They both add items to the view data.

Syntax-wise, `View::make()` only accepts an array while `with()` takes both, two strings:

```
with('booksList', $booksList);
```

Or an array that can possibly hold multiple variables:

```
with(array('booksList' => $booksList, 'foo' => $bar));
```

This also means that `compact()` can be used with `with()` as well:

```
return View::make('books.index')->with(compact($booksList));
```

Comment: Thanks, well detailed.

Answer (score 2):

The compact method passes array data to Constructor which is stored to `$data` Class attribute :

```
public function __construct(Factory $factory, EngineInterface $engine, $view, $path, $data = array())
    {
        $this->view = $view;
        $this->path = $path;
        $this->engine = $engine;
        $this->factory = $factory;

        $this->data = $data instanceof Arrayable ? $data->toArray() : (array) $data;
    }
```

While `with()` method accepts an array or a string, and in case it is an array it performs array_merge on the parameter otherwise it appends the data to a key which you passed as a paramter to `$data` attribute, so if you use constructor you're forced to pass an `array`, while `with()` accepts a single key with a value.

```
public function with($key, $value = null)
    {
        if (is_array($key))
        {
            $this->data = array_merge($this->data, $key);
        }
        else
        {
            $this->data[$key] = $value;
        }

        return $this;
    }
```