# Laravel 5.2 - Download Files From Database

Tags: php, database, laravel, file-upload, laravel-5

**These are what I have :**

Database table named `lamanInformasi`, which has these fields: id, judul, isi, created_at, updated_at.

**This is what I want :**

User can upload document and the files will be stored to database. The file names will be saved to `isi` field, and the files itself will be saved to a folder named propic. I've done all of them correctly. Then, I have a problem. When the data from database is showed, there are links in each file name. When user clicks the link, the file will be automatically downloaded. How to make it possible? When I click the link, I have this error: `NotFoundHttpException`

**These are my codes :**

*index.blade.php -- I put this file inside upload folder*

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" border= "1px solid black">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>Judul</td>
            <td>Isi</td>
            <td>Created At</td>
            <td>Updated At</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($lamanInformasi as $file)
        <tr>
             <td>{{$file->id}}</td>
             <td>{{$file->judul}}</td>
             <td><a href="{{URL::to('upload/' . $file->id)}}">{{$file->isi}}</a></td>
             <td>{{$file->created_at}}</td>
             <td>{{$file->updated_at}}</td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

*LamanInformasiController*

```
public function show($id)
{
    $lamanInformasi = $this->model->whereId($id)->firstOrFail();
    $downloadFile = response()->download($lamanInformasi->filepath, $lamanInformasi->name);
    return view('upload.index', compact('lamanInformasi','downloadFile'));
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Selamat pagi. You can check on your console if the `href` is pointing on the right directory. :)

Comment: @LaraBelle Selamat pagi. How to check it?

Comment: f12 to open console. Then try to find the `anchor` `<a href="must/be/on/upload/srcoffile">` tag with the link on it.

Comment: I can't find `anchor` tag

Comment: I am confuse on how do you want to achieve it. You can achieve it by pointing href into the file which is better. However, you can achieve it using laravel method. What method do you want to use?

Comment: post your route file

Answer (score 0):

The 'NotFoundHttpException' means Laravel wasn't able to find a route to for the request. So try it

```
 <td><a href="{{URL::to('upload')}}/{{ $file->id}}">{{$file->isi}}</a></td>
```

On controller

```
    return view('upload.index', array('lamanInformasi'=>$lamanInformasi,'downloadFile'=>$downloadFile));
```

Comment: how you maintain your routing for uploading files?

Comment: I just have this one route: `Route::resource('/upload8','LamanInformasiController');`

Comment: return view('upload.index', compact('lamanInformasi','downloadFile')); in this line why you are using compact function. Use array rather than compact function.

Comment: return view('upload.index', array('lamanInformasi'=>$lamanInformasi,'downloadFile'=>downloadFile));

Comment: @HikmatSijapati check compact first in PHP documentation. It's not laravel function. http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php how does it differs on array la?

Comment: @ Lara Belle http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28463779/whats-the-difference-between-with-and-compact-in-laravel

Comment: @HikmatSijapati I both used it quite alot on my projects. But what's the problem using native php compact with this problem? :)

Answer (score 0):

just use `download={{$report->name}}`

`download={{$report->name}}` -It  will make the download file name **download="filename"**, 
"**filename**" becomes the name of the downloaded file. and force to download and href tells where the file is

in **controller**

```
  public function download()
     {
        //display all types of reports from database name downloads

        $reports = DB::table('downloads')->all();  
       return view('reports.proposal',compact('reports'));
     }
```

and my **view** with a link to download is like this

```
@foreach($reports as $report)

             <a href="../backend/uploads/{{$report->name}}" download="{{$report->name}}">{{$report->name}}</a>

@endforeach
```

**youtube link**:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AlnackyPJPY

**gitlab link**:https://gitlab.com/Bons/download-files-laravel5