# laravel controller compact doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel

In my Routes I have:

```
Route::get('/about','PagesController@about');
```

In PagesController:

```
public function about()
{
    $people=['Taylor','Matt','Jeffrey'];
    return view('pages.about',compact($people));
}
```

if I use

```
return view('pages.about',['people'=> $people]);
```

It runs ok.

The controller isn't passing the array to view, why ?

Comment: `compact('people')`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22413121/6521116

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use 
`compact('people')`

If you're a beginner checkout the laracasts video series to get a good understanding of the Laravel framework.

Answer (score 3):

Remove `$` sign inside `compact` function like `compact('people')`. This will solve your issue.

compact() is not a Laravel function. It is a PHP function. It creates an array containing variables and their values.

For an example, assume you have following variables.

```
$name = 'Jon Snow';
$dad = 'Rhaegar Targaryen';
$mom = 'Lyanna Stark';
```

If you put those in a `compact()` as follows,

```
$thePrinceThatWasPromised = compact(['name', 'dad', 'mom']);
```

You'll get following array assigned to `$thePrinceThatWasPromised`.

```
[
    'name' => 'Jon Snow',
    'dad' => 'Rhaegar Targaryen',
    'mom' => 'Lyanna Stark'
]
```

For more information go to [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php)