# Passing an array from controller to view laravel using compact

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm using laravel 5.3 (make:auth automatic register and user authentication generator), and I would like to let user choose their tags in the registration form.

I wanna pass `$tags = App\Tag::all();` to the `register.blade.php` file located in `views\auth\register.blade.php`.

I found this method:

```
public function showRegistrationForm()
{
    return view('auth.register');
}
```

and I would like to do:

```
public function showRegistrationForm()
{
    $tags = App\Tag::all();
    return view('auth.register', compact($tags));
}
```

but I get undefined variable `'tags'` when trying to reach the `register.blade.php` file.

Comment: `return view('auth.register')->with(['tags'=>$tags]);`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22413121/6521116

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't feed the variable itself, provide the variable name when using `compact`.

```
return view('auth.register', compact('tags'));
```

Comment: Or just use vanilla declaration:

    return view('auth.register', array('tags' => $tags));

Answer (score 0):

First you need to know this :

**Models** , **Views** , **Controller** ;

the controller is the center point ie gets data from model and passes the data to the view , or  plain view .So what does this mean :

```
public function showRegistrationForm()
    {
        return view('auth.register');
    }
```

this here returns a plain view .And this below returns a view with the model data , in your case `App\Tag:` and `App\Tag::all()` is a collection ie a container with a dataset  ;

```
public function showRegistrationForm()
    {
        $tags = App\Tag::all();
        return view('auth.register', compact($tags));
    }
```

or better yet instead of compacting the array just create a new array and pass the dataset , how ?

`return view('auth.register', ['tags' => $tags]);`

Here is how to debug your app :Use below method :

```
public function showRegistrationForm()
    {
        $tags = App\Tag::all();
        dd($tags);
        //return view('auth.register', compact($tags));
    }
```

Do you see an array or error ? if array then your dataset is being passed to view , if not then there is an error either that the model does not exist or something , just check your log file .

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

if you want use compact then use like this

```
 return view('auth.register', compact('tags'));
```

in laravel 5.3 they have change like below but even you can use both methods :)

```
return view('auth.register', ['tags' => $tags]);
```