# How to work with Views without using PHP's "compact" function in LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel, function, laravel-5

I'm working on laravel to fetch data from database and store that data or array of data into the variable like $tasks store data of tasks table from database up till everything is fine but during processing the $task variable it is necessary to use "compact" function ?

And can anyone explain this

```
Route::get('/test', function () {

$data   =   [
                'name'  =>  'Vrushal',
                'last'  =>  'Raut',
                'tasks' =>  [
                                'Programming',
                                'UI/UX Developement',
                                'Cloud Expert'
                            ]
            ];
            //return view('templates/test', compact($data)); //NOT WORKING
            //return view('templates/test', $data); // ITS WORKING
            return View::make('templates/test',$data); // ITS WORKING
});
```

As well as with Database plz explain this

```
Route::get('/tasks', function(){

$tasks  =   DB::table('tasks')->get();

return view('templates/tasks', compact('tasks')); // ITS WORKING
//return View::make('templates/test',$tasks); // NOT WORKING
});
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: caveat, `compact` ignores variables that aren't set.

Comment: Actually 'compact' take number of variable and their values as an array.

Comment: **Folks I want solution for database code i.e**

`Route::get('/tasks', function(){

$tasks  =   DB::table('tasks')->get();

return view('templates/tasks', compact('tasks')); // ITS WORKING
//return View::make('templates/test',$tasks); // NOT WORKING
});`

Comment: if you took a second and read the manual for `compact`  and also actually took the time to see what is returned from that query, you would understand why this is.

Comment: @lagbox thanks a lot I think i figure out issue, if there any issue let you know.

Comment: awesome, you the man ;-) you got this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138411/discussion-between-vrushal-raut-and-lagbox).

Comment: @lagbox yo buddy :D

Comment: You can also use with http://stackoverflow.com/a/22413121/6521116

Answer (score 2):

`compact('data')` is the same as `['data' => $data]`, so to be able to access `Vrushal` value, you'll need to do this in the view:

```
{{ $data['name'] }}
```

When you do this:

```
 View::make('templates/test', $data);
```

You can get `Vrushal` value with:

```
{{ $name }}
```

Answer (score 2):

compact — Create array containing variables and their values
Manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php

```
<?php

$city  = "San Francisco";
$state = "CA";
$event = "SIGGRAPH";

$result = compact("event", "city", "state");
print_r($result);
//return view('templates/test', compact("event", "city", "state")); // ITS WORKING
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [event] => SIGGRAPH
    [city] => San Francisco
    [state] => CA
)
```

---

```
$arr = array(
    "city"  => "San Francisco",
    "state" => "CA",
    "event" => "SIGGRAPH"
);

extract($arr);    
$result = compact(array_keys($arr));
print_r($result);
//return view('templates/test', compact(array_keys($arr)); // ITS WORKING
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [event] => SIGGRAPH
    [city] => San Francisco
    [state] => CA
)
```

---

```
$arr = array(
     "city"  => "San Francisco",
     "state" => "CA",
     "event" => "SIGGRAPH"
);
print_r($arr);
//return view('templates/test', $data); // ITS WORKING
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [event] => SIGGRAPH
    [city] => San Francisco
    [state] => CA
)
```

---

```
$arr = array(
     "city"  => "San Francisco",
     "state" => "CA",
     "event" => "SIGGRAPH"
);
$result = compact($arr);
print_r($result);
//return view('templates/test', compact($arr)); //NOT WORKING
```

Result

```
Array
(

)
```

Answer (score 1):

`//return view('templates/test', compact($data)); //NOT WORKING` its not working because you don't need dollar sign for compact elements. It should look like this:

`return view('templates.test', compact('data'));` and then you can access it by $data[] variable inside view.

Other way:

`return view('templates.test')->with('variable', $data);` and accessing this in view with `$variable[]`