# With() vs Compact() in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Is there any difference between `with()` and `compact()` ?

Which one is more efficient ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [laravel compact() and ->with()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22412832/laravel-compact-and-with)

Comment: You should be more clear which functions exactly https://laravel.com/api/5.4/search.html?search=with

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`with()` is a Laravel function and `compact()` is a PHP function and have totally different purposes.

`with()` allows you to pass variables to a view and `compact()` creates an array from existing variables given as string arguments to it.

See [compact()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) for more info on this matter.

Answer (score 8):

`with()` is a method made available by method from one of their classes while `compact()` is a method that is available by default in `PHP` The `with()` cannot be used outside laravel but the `compact()` can be used anywhere in the `PHP` script.

The `compact()` function is used to convert given variable to to array in which the key of the array will be the name of the variable and the value of the array will be the value of the variable.

Answer (score 1):

### compact is php function :

> `compact` — Create array containing variables and their values

`compact()` takes a variable number of parameters. Each parameter can be either a `string` containing the name of the variable, or an `array` of variable names. The array can contain other **arrays** of variable names inside it; compact() handles it recursively.

### Method `with()` on Eloquent model enables for you eager loading.

Sometimes you may need to eager load several different relationships in a single operation.
To do so, you can just pass additional arguments to the `with` method:

```
$userss = App\User::with(['name', 'email'])->get();
```

when you want to pass multiple variables into a view One way to do so involves passing them into the `with` method using an array:

```
public function index()
{

    $data = array('name' => 'some one',
                  'email' => 'someone@gmail.com',
                  'date' => date('Y-m-d'));  

    return view('welcome')->with($data);

}
```

You could also use multiple with methods, like so:

```
return view('welcome')->with('name', 'some one')->with('email','someone@gmail.com)->with('date', date('Y-m-d'));
```

if you needed to pass along more than two variables. You can save some typing by using PHP's `compact()` function:

```
$name = 'some one';
$email= 'someone@gmail.com';
$date = date('Y-m-d');
return view('welcome', compact('name','email', 'date'));
```

or,if you needed to pass multiple arrays to a view you can use compact() function:

```
$array1 = ... ;
$array2 = ... ;
$array3 = ... ;
return view('welcome', compact('array1', 'array2', 'array3');
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, with() is used when you want to pass a single variable to a view, while compact() is used when you want to pass multiple variables to a view. However, the choice between these two functions ultimately depends on your personal preference and the specific use case.