# Undefined variable in views laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to call variable to views in laravel, but something not working
here is my controller

```
public function index($id,$slugify, Request $request,WiuCookie $wcookie)
{
    $user = ActionUsers::where('id', $id)->first();
    $petition = Petitions::where('slug',$slugify)->first();
    $isSigned = $wcookie->checkId($petition->id);

    return view('layouts.master',compact('user','petition','isSigned'));
}
```

and here is my view

```
@if($isSigned)
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            {{$user->name}}
        </a>
    </li>
    @else
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            register
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            log-in
        </a>
    </li>
@endif
```

and error is Undefined variable: user

Comment: take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22412832/laravel-compact-and-with

Comment: My guess is your query for `$user` returns `null`, try using `firstOrFail()` instead. Alternatively, you could typehint these arguments and use Laravel's route binding https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#implicit-binding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return view('layouts.master',compact(['user'=>$user,'petition'=>$petition,'isSigned'=>isSigned]));
```

It just works for me perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$compactData=array('user','petition','isSigned');
return View::make('layouts.master', compact($compactData));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this in passing remove compact and pass using with

```
  ->with('user',$user)
```