# How to show records from two different tables in same view using Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I want to show two different table records in the same view. How can I do this?

**Model Digitizingorder**

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Digitizingorder extends Model
{
    protected $table="digitizing_orders";
    protected $fillable =['id','order_name','height','width','image', 'order_placement','required_format','order_fabric','instruction','user_id'];
}
```

**Model Vectororder**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Vectororder extends Model
{
    protected $table ="vector_orders";
    protected $fillable =['id','vector_name','height','width','image','color', 'order','order_fabric','instruction','user_id'];
```

**HTML view**

```
<table id="selection-datatable" class="table table-sm mb-2">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>S.N </th>
            <th>Order No</th>
            <th>Design Name </th>
            <th>Order Type</th>
            <th>Received Date</th>
            <th>Released Date   </th>
            <th>price</th>
            <th>Order Details</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Your question is incomprehensible.. Please show what you did, what you want, and try by yourself first

Comment: Actually I want to show record of two different table in the same view

Answer (score 2):

call your model in the method you are returning the view:

```
public function view(){
$value1 = App\Digitizingorder::all();
$value2 = App\Vectororder::all();
return view('home')->with(['Digitizingorder'=>$value1,'Vectororder'=>$value2]);
```

then in your home.blade.php you can get it like this:

```
<p>{{$Digitizingorder}}<p>
<p>{{$Vectororder}}<p>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have two models with different table field names. but in the view, you are showing the common fields from the tables. So it becomes easy for you to accomplish this just pass the model data to the view and iterate them one by one.

**What you can do?**

> $digitizingorders = App\Digitizingorder::all();
>
> $vectororders = App\Vectororder::all();
>
> return view('your-view-file-name')->with(compact("digitizingorders","vectororders"));

now, these two variables will be available in your view and you can iterate the values easily like below.

```
<table id="selection-datatable" class="table table-sm mb-2">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>S.N </th>
            <th>Order No</th>
            <th>Design Name </th>
            <th>Order Type</th>
            <th>Received Date</th>
            <th>Released Date   </th>
            <th>price</th>
            <th>Order Details</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($digitizingorders as $dorder)
          <tr>
            <th>S.N </th>
            <th>Order No</th>
            <th>Design Name </th>
            <th>Order Type</th>
            <th>Received Date</th>
            <th>Released Date   </th>
            <th>price</th>
            <th>Order Details</th>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
        @foreach($vectororders as $vorder)
          <tr>
            <th>S.N </th>
            <th>Order No</th>
            <th>Design Name </th>
            <th>Order Type</th>
            <th>Received Date</th>
            <th>Released Date   </th>
            <th>price</th>
            <th>Order Details</th>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Actually I have question can i use  one  loop  for two table ?

Comment: your solution is completely wrong!! you cant use compact inside with method

Comment: @arya_la your comment "you cant use compact inside with method"!! Where did you get that? Please take a look at the laravel documentation. Just for your reference take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22412832/laravel-compact-and-with

Comment: @Zubair to do it in one loop you need to merge the two collections of data. One way is to convert the collection into an array and then merge those array into one array. next, pass it to the view. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-toarray